# Ignore specific key from terraform outputs or locals

Tags: syntax, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have the following code:

```
locals {
  env-list    = [for k, v in local.all-env-vars : { "${k}" : v }]
  test-list = [for k, v in local.test-env-vars : { "${k}" : v }]

  ssm    = setsubtract(local.env-list, local.test-list)
  test   = setsubtract(local.test-list, local.env-list)
}

output "diffs" {
  value = {
    ssm_only : nonsensitive([for s in local.ssm : keys(s)[0]]),
    test_only : nonsensitive([for s in local.test : keys(s)[0]]),
  }
}
```

Now, what I need to do is that - in the `ssm_only` - there is this one key called "EXAMPLE_KEY" which I do not want it to include in the outputs - so meaning ignore it.

I  really do not know how to do this... should I modify the `local.ssm` or the `ssm_only` output, and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given each of the keys in `local.ssm` is `s`, one way is to apply a conditional in your for-loop to filter elements for the `ssm_only` output:

`if s != "EXAMPLE_KEY"`

```
# ...
output "diffs" {
  value = {
    ssm_only : nonsensitive([for s in local.ssm : keys(s)[0] if s != "EXAMPLE_KEY"]),
  }
}
```

If you don't want it on the local level, you can apply a similar logic to the `locals`:

```
locals {
  env-list  = [for k, v in local.all-env-vars : { "${k}" : v } if k != "EXAMPLE_KEY"]
  test-list = [for k, v in local.test-env-vars : { "${k}" : v } if k != "EXAMPLE_KEY"]
  # ...
}
```

Please note I didn't test this code, but hopefully this helps!

Docs: https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/for#filtering-elements

Comment: this first suggestion for "output "diffs" gave some errors but the second suggestion worked fine!! THANK YOU!

Comment: I have one more question.. what if in the future I need to add more keys to ignore.. how would I do that? like what if I also need to ignore "EXAMPLE_KEY2" ? @cody.codes - ty

Comment: Sure thing. You can use Boolean logic operators here e.g. `(if k != "EXAMPLE_KEY" || if k != "EXAMPLE_KEY2")`
https://www.terraform.io/language/configuration-0-11/interpolation#conditionals